# Magento 2.3: Getting wrong product count on category page

Tags: magento2.3, category, products

I'm facing a strange issue which I couldn't point out where am I wrong. The issue is, when I navigate to any category page, the total result of product is showing as 1 though the category having many products.

But when I search the product via search bar, I'm getting the correct result of product counts.

Could anyone please help me to sort out this issue?

Code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Product list toolbar
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
 */
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\ProductList\Toolbar;
?>
<p class="toolbar-amount total-result" id="toolbar-amount">
    <?php if ($block->getLastPageNum() > 1): ?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Items %1-%2 of %3',
            '<span class="toolbar-number">' . $block->getFirstNum() . '</span>',
            '<span class="toolbar-number">' . $block->getLastNum() . '</span>',
            '<span class="toolbar-number">' . $block->getTotalNum() . '</span>') ?>
    <?php elseif ($block->getTotalNum() == 1): ?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('%1 Total Result',
           '<span class="toolbar-number">' . $block->getTotalNum() . '</span>') ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('%1 Total Result',
            '<span class="toolbar-number">' . $block->getTotalNum() . '</span>') ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw this happen when a `group by` statement is added to the product collection.
If this is the case, you can create an after plugin for the product collection that looks like this

```
public function afterGetSelectCountSql(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $subject
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Select $select;
) {
    $select->reset('group');
    return $select;
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me where I have to put this code?

Comment: You can find here the documentation about plugins: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will check it.